# SASS compile expanded and compressed CSS and rename the output

Tags: css, command-line, sass

I am using the command line `sass --watch style.scss --style compressed` to output a compressed CSS version of my SCSS style sheet.

Is there a way to output one expanded and one compressed CSS file, calling them respectively style.css and style.min.css?

I read the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) without finding any information on this.

Comment: Maybe concating the two commands with `&` on windows or `;` on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run two terminal windows, each with one watcher in it. In one you would run

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style nested
```

and in the other you would run

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.min.css --style compressed
```

I am unaware of a method to do this in one line.

Comment: What should we do for muti files? and compile all files in a folder?

Comment: @Hamid, you should be able to put the folder name right there instead of the file name. If you have a folder call `src/styles` and want to output to say `dist/styles` you would run:
`sass --watch src/styles:dist/styles`

Comment: I know. It wasn't my answer, I mean how to compile all files in a folder and have two versions of files (both nested and compressed (compressed with a different name))

Comment: Then I guess you could run two watchers simultaneously, using the same folder names for input and output, and then adding the respective `--style` parameters to those watchers. That should output two different versions of all the files.

Comment: No, It's not possible, because both of them try to compile as the same name

Comment: Aha, now I see. Well, it looks like that's not possible with the sass cli alone. Take a look here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335867/specify-output-file-names-when-watching-a-whole-directory-with-node-sass

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to go with a task manager like Gulp or Grunt. Then you can specify two separate task for SASS and run grunt compile (using the Grunt example below). One for compressed and one for expanded. Otherwise I would just run another command on the terminal if you don't wan to mess with the config.

```
sass: {

expanded: {
    options: {
         style: 'expanded'
    },
    files: {
         'css-expanded/*.css': 'sass/*.scss'
    }
}
compressed: {
    options: {
         style: 'compressed'
    }
    files: {
         'css-compressed/*.min.css': 'sass/*.scss'
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('compile': ['sass:expanded', 'sass:compressed']);
```